# Elementor WordPress Menu Always Breaks

Tags: wordpress, menu, elementor

I have a wordpress page and menu inside, but menu occasionaly breaks for no reason
[This is how its supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xc9u.png)
[And this is how it looks when breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBQ2L.png)
I found no info about on internet

I`ve fixed it somehow before, but i rewrote whole page
how can i fix it?((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by going into **Elementor>Tools** and clicking on **Regenerate Files and Data**. You should also clear the cache.

[image]